# Django form in a base class

Tags: python, django

**forms.py**

```
class search_form(forms.Form):
    options = categories.objects.all()
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(options, initial={'All':'All'}, label='')
    search = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='', required=False)
```

This form is used for searching for items. And right now I have it implemented on the index page and it works as expected. The index (home) page has its own view that makes use of this form, but I have a base template (base.html) that every page on the site extends. The base template holds the menu bar and the footer of the site. I need to add the form to the base class and have it function in every template that extends it.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [custom context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors), which is useful for passing data to every template context, which will give every template access to your form.

As explained in the docs, you need to make a function that will return a dictionary containing your form, and point to it in the settings.

Comment: thank you for the hint. Not knowing this, I subclassed the class based views and used my versions to return some additional context. This seems simpler, somehow :)